# How to access connection string in VS2012 WPF application from app.config?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using VS2012. I have to keep connection string in app.config and have to access it from my cs file. But I am unable to do it in VS2012. Following is what I have found from net but I think it works on earlier version of VS not on VS2012.

app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DataFormConnection"
            connectionString="Data Source=abcdd;database=xyz;uid=4566;pwd=987"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

How I am accessing it:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataFormConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Getting error: type or name does not exist in System.Configuration.ConfiguarationSettings

Comment: Why is this tagged "ASP.Net"? Is it WPF or ASP.Net? 2-tier or 3-tier? app.config or web.config?

Comment: Your error message says `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings` but your code is using `ConfigurationManager` - can you clarify that you aren't using `ConfigurationSettings` somewhere (I think this class was .NET 1/1.1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to references, and add a reference to `System.Configuration`.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `References`, and add a reference to `System.Configuration`

Once you have done this, you should be able to reference `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.